# How to use google tests's container matchers to check ValueObjects exist in a container?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have this exercise in C# that I'm trying to translate to C++.
I'd like to have some google tests using matchers to check the collection contents like I can in C#. The elements in the container are a user-defined ValueObject that has implemented the == operator so objects with the same data are equal.

It doesn't work and I don't know why?

This is what I want to write:

```
    std::vector<Character *> charactersList = finder.FindFamilyByLastName("Wheeler");
    ASSERT_THAT(charactersList, testing::Contains(*std::make_unique<Character>("Nancy", "Wheeler")));
    ASSERT_THAT(charactersList, testing::ElementsAre(
            *std::make_unique<Character>("Nancy", "Wheeler"),
            *std::make_unique<Character>("Mike", "Wheeler"),
            *std::make_unique<Character>("Karen", "Wheeler")
    ));
```

That's a snippet from: https://github.com/emilybache/StrangeCharacter-TestDesign-Kata/blob/main/cpp/test-gtest/ExampleCharacterTestCase.cpp

This is the C# version that does work:

```
    CollectionAssert.Contains(charactersList, new Character("Nancy", "Wheeler"));
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new List<Character>()
    {
        new Character("Nancy", "Wheeler"),
        new Character("Mike", "Wheeler"),
        new Character("Karen", "Wheeler"),
    }, charactersList);
```

That's a snippet from:
https://github.com/emilybache/StrangeCharacter-TestDesign-Kata/blob/main/csharp/StrangeCharacters/TestCharacters/ExampleCharacterTestCase.cs

Comment: Offtopic: this is silly: `*std::make_unique<Character>("Nancy", "Wheeler")`. Just should be `Character{"Nancy", "Wheeler"}`

Comment: Can you provide [mcve] using following link: https://godbolt.org/z/8s7fEPrdz ?

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* is not a problem description.

Comment: Please indicate what the problem is. If you get compiler errors then include them. If the code doesn't run correctly then say what happens, and what you expected to happen instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```cpp
        std::vector<Character *> charactersList = finder.FindFamilyByLastName("Wheeler");
```

you have vector of pointers.

```cpp
        ASSERT_THAT(charactersList, testing::Contains(*std::make_unique<Character>("Nancy", "Wheeler")));
```

Here you are trying compare elements of that array (a pointer) to a value, which is understandable for someone who uses C# more. In C++ this types are not comparable.
You where aware of pointer and added this performance killer `*make_unique` which is also form of over-engineering.

You need to compose matchers to access value from pointer. There is a matcher `testing::Pointee`:

```cpp
        ASSERT_THAT(charactersList, testing::Contains(testing::Pointee(Character("Nancy", "Wheeler"))));
```

Same thing should be done for `ElementsAre` (there is better way but to advanced).

Here is live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ocTx5hf6W

Comment: Thankyou! This "Pointee" construct does solve the problem for the "Contains" assertion. For the "ElementsAre" assertion it only partly solves the problem. It works but only if the elements are presented in the right order, something which the "ElementsAre" assertion is not supposed to enforce.

Comment: There are other matchers for containers. Check documentation: http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html `UnorderedElementsAre`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you don't appreciate how pointers work in C++. Coming from a C# background this is not surprising.

This

```
std::vector<Character *> charactersList = finder.FindFamilyByLastName("Wheeler");
```

is a vector of pointers. No overloading of `operator==` for a `Character` is going to help you find a `Character` pointer.

Since it is not possible to overload `operator==` for pointers I suggest you either change your code to use a vector of `Characters` (i.e. `std::vector<Character> charactersList = ...`) or if that is not possible use a different technique to find if one of the pointers in your vector points at a particular character. **EDIT:** As pointed out by Marek R, that different technique has already be implemented with `testing::Pointee`)

As already pointed out in the comments

```
*std::make_unique<Character>("Nancy", "Wheeler")
```

is a completely misguided way to say

```
Character("Nancy", "Wheeler")
```

You cannot program C++ like it is some minor variation on C#. The two languages are very very different. In C# you normally create objects with `new`. In C++ you rarely create objects with `new`.

Comment: Please consider your tone. In my opinion learners looking for advice should be met with kindness and clear explanation, not be admonished for their lack of knowledge.

Comment: @EmilyBache Sorry you took offence. My impression of you from your question was that you were an experienced programmer (in C#) and that you were just assuming that C++ was similar. Apologies if that is not the case. I don't think at any point I admonished you for your lack of knowledge.